# Nesting aliases in C#

Tags: c#, alias, typedef

I've seen lots of answers to the `typedef` problem in C#, which I've used, so I have:

```
using Foo = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Bar>;
```

and this works well.  I can change the definition (esp. change Bar => Zoo etc) and everything that uses Foo changes.  Great.

Now I want this to work:

```
using Foo = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Bar>;
using FooMap = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, Foo>;
```

but C# doesn't seem to like `Foo` in the second line, even though I've defined it in the first.

Is there a way of using an existing alias as part of another?

Edit: I'm using VS2008

Comment: Agree with Codesleuth - it still fails if Foo is an alias for a simple type (like System.Int32), so I'm guessing this is a compiler bug.

Comment: @Codesleuth @Dan, care to comment on Dave's answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the standard it looks like the answer is no.  From [Section 16.3.1](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/16.3.1.htm), paragraph 6:

> 1 The order in which
> using-alias-directives are written has
> no significance, and resolution of the
> namespace-or-type-name referenced by a
> using-alias-directive is not affected
> by the using-alias-directive itself or
> by other using-directives in the
> immediately containing compilation
> unit or namespace body.
>
> 2 In other
> words, the namespace-or-type-name of a
> using-alias-directive is resolved as
> if the immediately containing
> compilation unit or namespace body had
> no using-directives.

Edit:

I just noticed that the version at the above link is a bit out of date.  The text from the corresponding paragraph in the [4th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) is more detailed, but still prohibits referencing using aliases within others.  It also contains an example that makes this explicit.

Depending on your needs for scoping and strength of typing you might be able to get away with something like:

```
class Foo : System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Bar>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921944/2505186 this is possible when placing the
`using Foo = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Bar>;`
and
`using FooMap = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, Foo>;`
inside different namespaces, which in your case could be

```
----- cs-file -----
using System; (and others if needed)

using Foo = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Bar>;
namespace my_software
{
  using FooMap = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, Foo>;

  your usual code
}
----- file end -----
```

Your code would then probably be nested in an extra namepspace, which wouldn't be very nice just for this single purpose.